# CheckBoxList item search based on text in the textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to add search functionality to checkboxlist items so that I can search emp in the larger emp list which is directly loading from the database. I've already added (textbox, checkbox list) controls and some ajax(jquery) code  in the aspx file. But it's still not able to search by entering the text in the textbox. Can anyone please help me achieve the correct functionality.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        javascript:window.history.forward(0);                      
    </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SearchEmployees(ctl00$MainContent$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$txtSearch, ctl00_MainContent_lb_UserName) {
            if ($(ctl00$MainContent$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$txtSearch).val() != "") {
                var count = 0;
                $(ctl00_MainContent_lb_UserName).children('tbody').children('tr').each(function () {
                    var match = false;
                    $(this).children('td').children('label').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf($(ctl00$MainContent$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$txtSearch).val().toUpperCase()) > -1)
                            match = true;
                    });
                    if (match) {
                        $(this).show();
                        count++;
                    }
                    else { $(this).hide(); }
                });
                //  $('#spnCount').html((count) + ' match');
            }
            else {
                $(ctl00_MainContent_lb_UserName).children('tbody').children('tr').each(function () {
                    $(this).show();
                });
                $('#spnCount').html('');
            }
        }
```

---

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Height="190px" ScrollBars="Auto" style="text-align:left" Width="200px" Visible="False">
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" onkeyup="SearchEmployees(this,'#ctl00_MainContent_lb_UserName');"
                            placeholder="Search employee" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                         <span id="spnCount"></span> 
                            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="lb_UserName" DataTextField="Emp_Name" DataValueField="Emp_ID" DataSourceID="ds_User" runat="server" CssClass="bodyText" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="200px">
                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
                        </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have the same requirements and we leverage on using

> [select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage)

because it have search function and grouping available.

And for AJAX datasource you can refer to [select 2 remote data](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax)